# Solr: how to do a fq with a comma in the value

Tags: solr

How do I get an exact match with a fq where the field contains a comma in the string value? It seems solr is seeing this a CSV list and filters to either. I would like an exact match of the literal. For example: &fq=Location_s:Seattle, WA

Comment: what is the fieldtype of Location_s ?

Comment: dynamic of type string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Exact search use :

```
&fq=Location_s:"Seattle, WA"
```

Comment: For the benefit of others, note that exact search only works with double quotes, not single quotes.